# file_get_contents function not working

Tags: php, file, url, file-get-contents

I have some problem with `file_get_contents()` function, it not working properly when I tried to read URL like

> "http://google.com"

is accessible but when I tried to  access any file like "classes/connect_temp.txt" it is not accessible.

Here is some code i use

```
$file_path =realpath('./')."/classes/connect_temp.txt";
    $temp_cont = file_get_contents($file_path);
    if(empty($temp_cont)){$temp_cont=$this->dbSetings;}
```

What should I change in code or which config settings should I check of it.

Please Help me on this problem

Comment: Do you get any PHP error? Maybe the file doesn't exists or you don't have the right to read from it.

Comment: Or you absolutely, positively sure that $file_path contains the correct path?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that $file_path contains the correct path & it does not giving any error

Comment: What makes you say that the file is "not accessible"? Is $temp_cont always empty? Does it contain nonsense? What is in the file connect_temp.txt?

Comment: I mean $temp_cont always empty. and connect_temp.txt has connection template

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting using `display_errors` and/or `error_reporting`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
echo $file_path;
```

To check what file the code is really trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) ?

Sample..

```
$ch = curl_init("path-to-the-file");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);      
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```